# How to give Write Permission to public in Github Folder?

Tags: php, github, server, cloud, cloudways

My project is deployed in a server. Server is pulling from Github. I want, users can upload images in one folder in Github which is deployed in server. It is showing "Permission Denied".
How to give write access to that folder in github ?

I am using CloudWays PHP project. Deployed via Github.

Comment: on your server try to give chmod 777 to that folder

Comment: I tried through putty. In putty after giving id and password window shuts down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the permission of the directory and enable others to create files inside.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /yourfolderpath
```

This command will change the permission of the directory recursively and enable all other users to create/modify and delete files and directories inside.

Comment: I tried through putty. In putty after giving ip and login credentials window shuts down.

Comment: Can you re-launch the terminal for putty and try once again by going into the path and then fire the command which I have given as an answer.

Comment: What you mean by re-lunching the terminal?

Comment: The terminal where you can connect your server and access through commands.

Comment: Yes I tried through the terminal. I tried this command. and I pushed to Github. Still I am not able to push images into that folder.

Comment: "and I pushed to Github." You do not need to do anything with Github!  Just give permission for the needed folder and you are done!

Comment: You can do ls -l command to check if the folder has full permission or not ?